# Tinycarousel not sliding automatically

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins

I want to automatically slide my div with tinycarouosel.

Added the plugin in

```
vendors/assets/javascripts
```

In application.js

```
//= require jquery.tinycarousel.min

In my html file

 <% array_product_subscriptions.flatten.each do |subscription| %>
    <div class="contract-para"><%= "The Product is ready #{subscription.name}" %></div>
 <% end %>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.tinycarousel.min.js">
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $('.contract-para').tinycarousel();
          });
  </script>
```

In .css file

```
.contract-para{
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 20px;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

But it is not sliding my divs. It just displays my divs one by one.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're creating multiple divs, since you're looping it inside `each`, change it to this and then try:

```
<div class="contract-para">
  <% array_product_subscriptions.flatten.each do |subscription| %>
    <%= "The Product is ready #{subscription.name}" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry But this did not help.

Comment: You want it to slide automatically? Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: yes. It must display each subscription name in each slide.

Comment: For that I think you need to work on CSS. Look at the [examples here](https://baijs.com/tinycarousel/), they all have set width, height, and `overflow:hidden`. Also, pass: `tinycarousel({ interval: true });` if you want this to slide automatically in your JavaScript.